# Is it possible to set permissions in Perforce such that a user cannot integrate into a certain area of the depot?

Tags: permissions, perforce

In a perforce depot I have an area containing stable branches, and an area containing unstable branches. I want to control a users ability to create new branches (using p4 integrate) within the stable area. So for example my depot is laid out like so:

```
//depot
       /stable
              stable_branch_1/...
              stable_branch_2/...
              ... (I want users to be stopped from integrating to here)
       /unstable
              unstable_branch_1/...
              unstable_branch_2/...
              ... (I want users to be able to integrate to here)
```

I'm aware that in the p4 permissions I can set something like:

```
=branch     user     *         * -//depot/stable/...
```

([c.f.](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/p4sag/04_protect.html)) but this is the exact opposite of what I need (i.e. bans users from using stable as a *source* for integrations, rather than a target).

I'm very surprised that it doesn't seem possible to do what I want without resorting to using triggers, can anyone provide any suggestions?

Edit: Just to make clear I wan't users to continue to be able to write to the stable folder, I just want to prevent an integrate operation being performed with the stable folder as a target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,
combining the collective wisdom here and from our Perforce admin, I'd suggest the following:

```
write    user    *    *    -//depot/stable/...
write    user    *    *     //depot/stable/existing/branchA
write    user    *    *     //depot/stable/existing/branchB
```

i.e. take away write-rights from the stable-depot and then re-grant it again. Also, it is important to note the difference between `=write` and `write`. The first one grants exactly write-rights (and nothing else, no read, no sync, no nothing), the latter one grants write-rights and all lower level rights (e.g. read, sync).

Comment: Apologies, I didnt make that point in the post itself, I want users to be able to check in to existing branches, just not to be able to create new ones. I tried perforce support and they said it wasn't supported, I just thought I'd reach out here and ask because it seems like a strange omission.

Answer (score 2):

If you set explicit permissions on each subbranch in your stable area you should be able to give users full access to existing branches/projects you have created, but they will be unable to create new brances/projects

eg.  In your permissions file (I dont know the syntax and dont have perforce on this machine)

```
#  Do not give any permissions for  //depot/stable
write    user_group    *    *    //depot/stable/stable_Branch_1/...
write    user_group    *    *    //depot/stable/stable_Branch_2/...
write    user_group    *    *    //depot/stable/stable_Branch_3/...
```

etc

Your users should now not be able to create any new branches/projects/folders at the //depot/stable/... level but have full permissions above.  You cant prevent them from integrating into the existing branches though.  That I'm afraid involves user education!

Comment: +1 for that, I think, depending on the rest of the protection file, it would be necessary to explicitly take away write-rights to the //deport/stable path and then re-grant them to the specific paths.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your protections table will prevent the user from integrating *into* `//depot/stable` while still allowing them to integrate *from* it:

```
=write user * * -//depot/stable/...
```

Remember, order is important.  Perforce applies the permissions in the order that they are listed.  This...

```
=write user * * -//depot/stable/...
write user * * //...
```

...is no different than this:

```
write user * * //...
```

Also, Perforce throws a rather unintuitive error when a denied user attempts to integrate into the forbidden area.  Instead of saying something sensible like, "You do not have permission to write to this folder", it pops up this nonsense:

[alt text http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/4579/p4deniedintegration.png](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/4579/p4deniedintegration.png)